# RANKING for counting phone numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Thanks for all your suggestions.It works fine on a small test data but I guess I under-estimated the total rows and plans so I guess I will have to post some biggers sample data

Here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE MasterTable
(`Date` datetime, `PhNO` int, `Plan_name` varchar(13), `Plan_price` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO MasterTable
(`Date`, `PhNO`, `Plan_name`, `Plan_price`)
VALUES
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 3232222, 'Basepack1', '$32'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 3232222, 'Basepack2', '$31'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 3221111, 'Basepack6', '$21'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 543222, 'BaseValuePack', '$76'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 543222, 'Basepack1', '$30'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 32322221, 'Basepack1', '$37'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 32322221, 'Basepack2', '$21'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 32322354, 'Basepack7', '$23'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 32322254, 'Basepack8', '$11'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 3267767,  'Non-base1', '$21'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 3267762,  'Non-base1', '$21'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 32677676,  'Non-base3', '$76'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 5267767,  'Non-base9', '$21')
```

Now I basically want to group all the 'Non-base%' plans under 'Casual' category

Here is the desired output:

### Date                  Plan_name     Phone_no_count

'2014-01-01 13:00:00' 'Basepack1'     2
'2014-01-01 13:00:00' 'Basepack2'     0
'2014-01-01 13:00:00' 'Basepack6'     1
'2014-01-01 13:00:00' 'BaseValuepack' 1
'2014-01-01 13:00:00' 'Casual'        4

Thanks

...........................................
Previous request:
I need to count all the phone nos categorised by certain plans. But to group those plans, I need to rank them first based on their price.

Here is the ddl

```
CREATE TABLE MasterTable
    (`Date` datetime, `PhNO` int, `Plan_name` varchar(13), `Plan_price` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO MasterTable
(`Date`, `PhNO`, `Plan_name`, `Plan_price`)
VALUES
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 3232222, 'Basepack1', '$32'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 3232222, 'Basepack2', '$31'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 3221111, 'Basepack6', '$21'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 543222, 'BaseValuePack', '$76'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 543222, 'Basepack1', '$30'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 32322221, 'Basepack1', '$37'),
('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 32322221, 'Basepack2', '$21')
;
```

Now the rule is, I only need to count a phone no once who has more than 1 plan based on their plan price(higher one) .
But there is also a scenario where a phone no has two different 'packs'- Basepack and valuepack, which means  I need to count that phone no only once categorised under value pack(in this case we need to ignore the price).

Here is the desired output.

```
Date                  Plan_name     Phone_no_count
-------------------------------------------------
'2014-01-01 13:00:00' 'Basepack1'     2
'2014-01-01 13:00:00' 'Basepack2'     0
'2014-01-01 13:00:00' 'Basepack6'     1
'2014-01-01 13:00:00' 'BaseValuepack' 1
```

How do I use the rank function to achieve this result?

Comment: Is this really Sql-Server or Mysql ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Assuming it is mysql as the code posted looks like mysql

```
SELECT date, 
   plan_name, 
   Sum((SELECT Count(1) 
        FROM   mastertable T2 
        WHERE  t2.phno = tt.phno 
               AND t2.date = Tt.date 
               AND ( tt.plan_price > t2.plan_price 
                      OR TT.count = 1 ))) CNT 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
           (SELECT Count(1) 
            FROM   mastertable Ti 
            WHERE  ti.date = T.date 
                   AND ti.phno = t.phno) AS Count 
    FROM   mastertable T) Tt 
GROUP  BY date, 
      plan_name
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fce48/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by phno order by plan_price desc)rn 
from @MasterTable

)
,
cte1 as
(
select a.Plan_name,count(*)[Phone_no_count] from  cte a
 where rn=1
 group by a.Plan_name
)
select distinct a.dates,a.Plan_name,isnull(b.Phone_no_count,0)[[Phone_no_count]  
from @MasterTable a left join cte1 b on a.Plan_name=b.Plan_name
```